# Latex - Refer to nested item from enumerate in beamer

Tags: latex, enumerate, beamer

I want to refer to a nested item from an enumerate, but i want to see the entire label.
Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Top list
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Nested item 1
            \item \label{n2} Nested item 2
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    
    I refer to item \ref{n2}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

But I would like it to refer to item 1.2 instead of 2.

I know you can do this using enumitem, but that seems to be incompatible with beamer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}
  {\renewcommand\theenumii{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}  

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Top list
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Nested item 1
            \item \label{n2} Nested item 2
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    
    I refer to item \ref{n2}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LynnH You're welcome!